# How to add an image to be used in the customized css file - Swagger UI - Swashbuckle

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I'm using Swagger(Swashbuckle) as the documentation tool for our Web API project. I'm able to customize index.html using customized css file.
Everything's works great, except, I want to add our company's specific logo in the index page & I couldn't get it to work.

Suggestions ??

Answer (score 10):

I realize this is an older question, but I just ran into this today.  If you want to embed an image file, you can do it similar to how you do for the css and index file.

Add a line in the SwaggerConfig like the following:

```
c.CustomAsset("mylogo", thisAssembly, "YourWebApiProject.SwaggerExtensions.mylogo.png");
```

You can then reference that file either in your modified css or custom index page by using `<img src="mylogo" />` in your modified html or `url(../mylogo)` for the path if using it in your custom css file.

Similar to your index and css files, make sure it's set as an embedded resource.

Answer (score 1):

What about including this in your CSS:

```
.swagger-section #header a#logo {
  background-image: url(path/to/my/logo);
}
```